# Improving treap implementation

Tags: performance, optimization, data-structures, haskell, garbage-collection

Here's my implementation of a sort of treap (with implicit keys and some additional information stored in nodes): http://hpaste.org/42839/treap_with_implicit_keys

According to profiling data GC takes 80% of time for this program. As far as I understand, it's caused by the fact that every time a node is 'modified', each node on the path to the root is recreated.

Is there something I can do here to improve performance or I have to descend into the realm of ST monad?

Comment: @adamax: this behavior (recreate everything up to the root) is common in immutable structures, have you read Purely Functional Data Structures by Chris Okasaki ? http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf he wrote several papers on this.

Comment: Perhaps you should verify this by running your program with `+RTS -s -RTS` as I can't see this 80% you speak of when I gave it a quick run using 7.0.1, I see about 16% time spent in GC.

Comment: @ScottWest: I compile it with ghc -O2 -prof --make test.hs and run with ./test +RTS -s -RTS, it says  %GC time 77.4%  (77.4% elapsed), the total time is 8.7 seconds. But my ghc version is 6.12.1. Just out of interest, what is the total time at your system?

Comment: @adamax: Try it without the -prof flag, the usages are much lower, I suspect. With the -prof -auto-all flags mine stack overflows.

Comment: @Mathhieu: I understand that this behaviour is inherent to functional data structures, but maybe I'm missing something and the true reason for the poor performance is the growth of stack or something?

Comment: @ScottWest: Oh, I thought -prof is required for runtime statistics. I tried it with -O2 but without -prof, it's 81.8%. Without -O2 it stackoverflows here as well.

Comment: @adamax, I suppose the last variable is the GHC version. The times for the successful (non-prof) run is about 6.5 seconds.

Comment: @adamax, I have about the same results as you.  With ghc-7.0.1 and -O2, runtime is 8.027s and productivity is 16.8%.  If I compile with -O2 -funfolding-use-threshold=256, runtime is 3.863s and productivity is 24.9%.  I tried a few other options and INLINE'ing stuff, but this is the best I've got so far.

Comment: I don't think you should be using strict Trees for the branches `left` and `right`, this may cause more copying than necessary.

Comment: @adamax, forgot to mention I had similar results with ghc-6.12.1.

Comment: @luqui, non-strict Trees for the branches are slightly worse by my tests.  The strictifications in the file are optimal AFAICT (although the `UNPACK` pragma is ignored on the branches).

Comment: a small improvement: remove the `!`'s from the where-bound vars `first`, `second` in `merge`, and from `t` in `split`.  I expected these would be irrelevant, but removing them saves about 0.5s.

Comment: @adamax, is it possible to redefine `split` using a bottom-up traversal?  I think this would be much more efficient.

Comment: @John, by bottom-up traversal you mean avoiding a recursive call of split? I doubt it's possible. It's kind of a standard algorithm, I would be surprised if there were a better way.

Comment: Note that `UNPACK` has no effect on sum types i.e. using `UNPACK` on the `left` and `right` fields has no effect.

Comment: Don't forget GHC's options for garbage collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171922/ghcs-rts-options-for-garbage-collection

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using GHC 7.0.3, I can reproduce your heavy GC behavior:

```
  $ time ./A +RTS -s
  %GC time      92.9%  (92.9% elapsed)
  ./A +RTS -s  7.24s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 7.301 total
```

I spent 10 minutes going through the program. Here's what I did, in order:

- Set GHC's -H flag, increasing limits in the GC
- Check unpacking
- Improve inlining
- Adjust the first generation allocation area

Resulting in a 10 fold speedup, and GC around 45% of time.

---

In order, using GHC's magic `-H` flag, we can reduce that runtime quite a bit:

```
  $ time ./A +RTS -s -H
  %GC time      74.3%  (75.3% elapsed)
  ./A +RTS -s -H  2.34s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 2.392 total
```

Not bad!

The UNPACK pragmas on the `Tree` nodes won't do anything, so remove those.

Inlining `update` shaves off more runtime:

```
 ./A +RTS -s -H  1.84s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 1.883 total
```

as does inlining `height`

```
 ./A +RTS -s -H  1.74s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 1.777 total
```

So while it is fast, GC is still dominating -- since we're testing allocation, after all.
One thing we can do is increase the first gen size:

```
 $ time ./A +RTS -s -A200M
 %GC time      45.1%  (40.5% elapsed)
 ./A +RTS -s -A200M  0.71s user 0.16s system 99% cpu 0.872 total
```

And increasing the unfolding threshold, as JohnL suggested, helps a little,

```
 ./A +RTS -s -A100M  0.74s user 0.09s system 99% cpu 0.826 total
```

which is what, 10x faster than we started? Not bad.

---

Using [ghc-gc-tune](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-gc-tune), you can see runtime as a function of `-A` and `-H`,

[image: Time and GC]

Interestingly, the best running times use very large `-A` values, e.g.

```
$ time ./A +RTS -A500M   
./A +RTS -A500M  0.49s user 0.28s system 99% cpu 0.776s
```

Comment: Wow, that's incredible! I have a similar behaviour with ghc 6.12.1, the biggest speedup is given by inlining `update` and setting first gen size. One question, did you forget to include `size` option for -H? Just -H doesn't seem to do anything, while -H64m, for instance, does.

Comment: With GHC 7, -H increases all the limits for  the GC

Comment: More precisely, -H is a kind of "automatic -A", it increases the -A setting but without increasing the overall memory use.  This is possible because we're doing copying GC, so between major GCs there's a lot of memory going unused.  Increasing -A is not always a good idea - in some programs it will make things worse, due to increased cache misses.