# Haskell parallel performance

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, parallel-processing

The task is to speed up a summation by using parMap or parListChunk or better. It actually runs slower with parallelism code.

**Edit:**  *Facepalm*.. I overlooked how to execute the application correctly.

Don't forget to add cores by

```
./myHaskellApp paramaters +RTS -N4 -sstderr
```

Where N**4** is number of cores.

Comment: Are these also slower for really big lists?

Comment: Depending on how expensive `euler` is, `5` may be much too small a chunk size.  What if you try something more like 2000?  (Although considering the smallitude of 15000, `euler` is probably fairly expensive, in which case this wouldn't work)

Comment: The best tool to analyze your parallel program is http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope

Comment: Considering that the list doesn't even exist for the non parallel case (it compiles down to a non-allocating loop) but for the parallel case you must allocate a large list, chop it into chunks, and spark work.  Are you really surprised?  If you post the full code I might give it a look later.

Comment: I will try larger chunks later.

Comment: Ah jeez! I didn't run the application with correct arguments to add more cores to the execution.

Comment: Performance Hint ;-} tag your haskell questions "Haskell"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always make sure that you're actually running `-threaded`, optimzied with `-O2`, and you are using a reasonable number of cores (e.g. `-N4`). Furthermore, check your [garbage collector statistics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171922/ghcs-rts-options-for-garbage-collection)