# What do GHC's garbage collector options -A and -H mean?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've read on the [GHC's documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-options-to-control-the-garbage-collector) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171922/ghcs-rts-options-for-garbage-collection) about the `-A`
and `-H` options. The first one sets a fixed size for the "allocation area" (or the generation 0 of the garbage collector). The second sets a lower bound on the heap size. If I understand well how generational garbage collection works, objects are allocated on generation 0, and when this one is full, those that are still needed are copied to generation 1 and the others are deallocated. My question is how are "allocation area", generation 0, generation 1, and heap size related? Is it like this:

- allocation area = generation 0,
- generation 0 + generation 1 (+ eventually more generations) = heap size?

Then, does -A controls the size of the first one whereas -H sets a lower bound on the size of the whole?